# Prevent word from updating all fields when inserting a caption

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

When I insert a caption, depending on the document's size, it could take several seconds because Word is updating all fields and it's annoying.

How to prevent word from updating all fields when inserting a caption?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Word doesn't seem to have this function, how about unlinking with Ctrl+Shift+F9?